# Mandrill version 3 Ping() method

Tags: c#, asp.net, mandrill

In the previous version of Mandrill, I was using the following piece of code ( written in C# based on ASP.NET framework):

```
MandrillApi mapi = new MandrillApi(
            SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetValue("MandrillAPIKey"),
            SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetBoolValue("MandrillUseSSL"),
            SettingsKeyInfoProvider.GetIntValue("MandrillTimeout"));

// validate and respond
string pingResult = mapi.Ping();

if (pingResult.ToUpper().Contains("PONG!"))
    return mapi;
```

After updating the Mandrill version to 3 and how can I get the "PONG" message from Ping() method, previously the Ping() method had a return type string, but now in Mandrill version 3 the Ping() method has the return type as `Task<string>`. I tried debugging the code but not able to find the message as "PONG".

I tried to google and the possible solutions I found did not work.

Also I tried `string pingResult = mapi.Ping().Result;` which returns a string but it throws an exception.

Can anyone please help?

**Edit:** I am facing the deadlock in the following:

[image]

Without `ConfigureAwait(false)` getting the same issue. At this point as mentioned in above screenshot, the page loads infinitely and no result shows up.

Answer (score 0):

If the return type of any Method is `Task<T>` or `Task` you can await that method. This change was probably done so that if Ping takes a while (e.g if it times out) it wont be blocking the Thread for a long time.

To get the string, you can either `await` the method call:

```
string pingResult = await mapi.Ping();
```

But you can only do this in an `async` Context, so if the Method declaration is marked with async. Or, if your context is synchronous, you can do this:

```
string pingResult = mapi.Ping().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Comment: Thanks, but after using either of the above code`string pingResult = await mapi.Ping();` or `string pingResult = mapi.Ping().GetAwaiter().GetResult();`, it ends up in a deadlock and the page loads infinitely. Please suggest for the same.

Comment: How exactly are finding out that it ends in a deadlock?

Comment: I have edited my question and added the screenshot. Can you please check and suggest for the same?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also, this tells me nothing. What is your reasoning behind this being a deadlock?